# Как определить на кого был сделан реплай в pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Бот на pyTelegramBotAPI.
Нужно чтобы в группе когда человек делает реплай на чьё-то сообщение и пишет определленную команду, выводилось сообщение с именем оправителя и человека на кого был сделан реплай. И у меня вопрос как определить человека на которого был сделан реплай.

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types="text")
def test(message):
    try:
        print('исходный текст:', message.reply_to_message.text)
        print('текст реплая:', message.text)
        print('пользователь исходного текста:', message.reply_to_message.from_user.username)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)

>>> исходный текст: исходный текст пользователя 1
>>> текст реплая: реплай от пользователя 2
>>> пользователь исходного текста: username
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]